# Calling a perl script from bash/shell script

Tags: perl, shell, cron

I'm trying to call a perl script (from a shell script) that is located in different directories based on which environment it is called from in the cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
# triggerCron.sh - set different environments, set path to perl scripts, calls script

TMP_HOME=/home/localweb/htdocs/cgi-bin/user1/localroot

if [ "$1" = "dev" ] || [ "$1" = "uat" ] || [ "$1" = "prd" ]
then
echo "Calling $1 OBTriggerCron.pl"
export PATH=$TMP_HOME/$1:$PATH
echo $PATH
./OBTriggerCron.pl
echo "Complete."
else
    echo "Val Not Set: $1"
fi
```

My thinking was I could export the path first, then call the script...  Then just have a crontab that looks like this:

```
30 4 * * * /usr/bin/triggerCron.sh dev
30 4 * * * /usr/bin/triggerCron.sh uat
30 4 * * * /usr/bin/triggerCron.sh prd
```

But when I run it I get:

```
bash-3.00$ triggerCron.sh dev
Calling dev OBTriggerCron.pl
/home/localweb/htdocs/cgi-bin/user1/localroot/dev:/home/localweb/htdocs/cgi-bin/user1/localroot/dev:/home/localweb/htdocs/cgi-bin/user1/localroot/dev:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/ufs/00/home/user1/bin:/ufs/00/home/user1/mysql-tools:/home/ICoracle/bin
Can't open perl script "OBTriggerCron.pl": No such file or directory
```

Basically, I'm trying to TEMPORARILY set the path, call the script and exit...  but so far, no luck...  Yes, there is a copy of the OBTRiggerCron.pl script in each directory.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Run `pwd` in your script to show its current working directory, it may not be what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
./OBTriggerCron.pl
```

Do:

```
$TMP_HOME/$1/OBTriggerCron.pl
```

No need to export PATH in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
./OBTriggerCron.pl
```

Means execute the OBTriggerCron.pl in current directory. You need

```
OBTriggerCron.pl
```

which will look in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help!  Both answers helped, but the biggest help was Lee Duhem....  There are settings files (yml) that I am calling and I **need to make sure I was in the right director**y...  So I took everyone's suggestions and it looks like this now:

```
TMP_HOME=/home/localweb/htdocs/cgi-bin/user1/localroot

if [ "$1" = "dev" ] || [ "$1" = "uat" ] || [ "$1" = "prd" ]
then
echo "Calling $1 OBTriggerCron.pl"
cd $TMP_HOME/$1
OBTriggerCron.pl
echo "Complete."
else
echo "Val Not Set: $1"
fi
```

and it works!  Thanks Everyone!